Spark Streaming Not able to read from a remote host:port
I am writing a Spark Streaming application that listens to a specific TCP port, reads any data whenever it appears there and then processes and generates reports. I am using Google Colab and Python 3. 
The following stuff WORKS
# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:9999
lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9000) \
    .load()

I am using NGROK tunnels to deliver data to port 8000
<NgrokTunnel: "tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:11475" -> "localhost:8000">

Then using a utility to program to transfer read port 8000 and write on port 9000 which is then correctly read in the Spark program. 
On a remote machine, which is also Google Colab, i am using the following command to transmit data
!echo 'Hello Chek Hello Chek Mike Testing Hello Chek' > /dev/tcp/0.tcp.ngrok.io/11475

All this is working just fine.

Problem starts when I use NGROK tunnel on a remote machine and try to read the data in the Spark program using this command
# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:9999
lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "4.tcp.ngrok.io") \
    .option("port", 13434) \
    .load()

On the remote machine I have mapped port 7984 as
<NgrokTunnel: "tcp://4.tcp.ngrok.io:13434" -> "localhost:7984">

and using the following command to transmit data
!echo 'Hello Chek Hello Chek Mike Testing Hello Chek' | nc  localhost 7984

There is no error message anywhere but the data is not being received / read / processed in the Spark Streaming program. What am I doing wrong?

Looks like even netcat cannot reach and read the ngrok tunnel exit point! # nc -lk -s 0.tcp.ngrok.io -p 11659
nc: Cannot assign requested address
